# android: Set ToggleButton background back to default

Tags: android, android-layout

I changed the background for a ToggleButton and wish to reset it back to its default state.

Changed the background:

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF2929"));
```

Tried changing it back:

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(0);                                  //Just text, no button
btn.setBackgroundColor(android.R.drawable.btn_default);        //Normal button not toggle
```

Comment: `btn.setBackgroundResource` is supposed to remove the background when `0` is passed. What's happening after `btn.setBackgroundColor(android.R.drawable.btn_default); ` ?

Comment: you are setting a drawable in Color, use "btn.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default)" instead. This should set something in your button.

Comment: @krishan Took the words right out of my mouth ;-) Perhaps you could post that as an answer instead!

Comment: @krishan If I use that it just gives me a normal Button not a ToggleButton. I uploaded [this] (https://ibb.co/mi9vvF) image to show. The top button is a ToggleButton and the one below is the android.R.drawable.btn_default.

Answer (score 2):

you are setting a drawable in Color, use `btn.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default)`. 
This should set something in your button.

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file under drawable folder and put this code , currently the xml file name I put is check.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@color/Your color"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@color/Your color"
    android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Put this code in your toggle button layout xml

```
android:background="@drawable/check"
```

This may help you.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not trying to set a colour based on whether its checked or not. I'm doing a trivia game and the colour depends on whether users input is correct. Button becomes green if it was correct, red if incorrect and at new question should go back to original background.